# Display a progress bar inside a UITextField object

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, uiprogressview

How can one draw a progressbar inside a `UITextField` ? I have tested two ways so far.

**1. Add a `UIProgressView` object as a subview of the `UITextField` object.**

```
UIProgressView* progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
[aUITextField addSubview:progressView];
progressView.progress = 0.5;
[progressView release];
```

**2. Subclass `UITextfield` and override `drawRect:`.**

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
    [[UIColor orangeColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect] fill];
}
```

Both approaches didn't work. Do you see any problem with these approaches? And how can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure adding the `UIProgressView` as a subview of a `UITextField` object will be useful as you can't change the frame of the progress view.

Subclassing seems to be the right approach. Here is what I could come up with. Check if it is useful to you.

**ProgressField.h**

```
@interface ProgressField : UITextField {

}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat progress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIColor * progressColor;

@end
```

**ProgressField.m**

```
@implementation ProgressField
@synthesize progress;
@synthesize progressColor;

- (void)setProgress:(CGFloat)aProgress {
    if ( aProgress < 0.0 || aProgress > 1.0 ) {
        return;
    }

    progress = aProgress;

    CGRect progressRect = CGRectZero;
    CGSize progressSize = CGSizeMake(progress * CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.bounds));
    progressRect.size = progressSize;

    // Create the background image
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, self.bounds);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self progressColor].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, progressRect);

    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [super setBackground:image];
}

- (void)setBackground:(UIImage *)background {
    // NO-OP
}

- (UIImage *)background {
    return nil;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        [self setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleBezel];
    }
    return self;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work with `UITextField`s with `borderStyle` set to `UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect`.

Comment: I try to use your codes, but still no preferred result. I will report the result if I get the correct display

Comment: Sure, you can look at [`this sample`](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22783696/ProgressField.zip). Use the slider to simulate change in `progress`.

Comment: Thanks aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa lot

Answer (score 1):

```
UIProgressView* progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] init];
progressView.frame = aUITextField.frame;// you can give even set the frame of your own using CGRectMake();
[aUITextField addSubview:progressView];
progressView.progress = 0.5;
[progressView release];
```

Set the progressview's frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here I think you have to add progressView  as subview to self.view , just set progressView's frame according to size that will fit in to UITextField , and make set center of progressview to center of UITextField .
 hope it will help you.